# Error "TypeError : not all arguments converted during string formatting" occurred during execution of program

Tags: python

The code which I have written:

```
def digit_sum(n):
    Even_sum = 0
    Odd_sum = 0
    for i in str(n):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            Even_sum += i
        else :
            Odd_sum += i
    if Even_sum > Odd_sum :
        return (Even_sum - Odd_sum)
    else :
        return (Odd_sum - Even_sum)
    
digit = str(input('Enter a number : '))
digit_sum(digit)
```

During the execution of the program, the following error is occurring :

```
Enter a number : 235435677346
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-b41697467c07> in <module>
     13 
     14 digit = str(input('Enter a number : '))
---> 15 digit_sum(digit)

<ipython-input-34-b41697467c07> in digit_sum(n)
      3     Odd_sum = 0
      4     for i in str(n):
----> 5         if i % 2 == 0:
      6             Even_sum += i
      7         else :

**TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting**
```

Why is this error occurring and what must be done to avoid this?

Comment: Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking its not clear what you want achieve thru this

Answer (score 0):

```
def digit_sum(n):
  Even_sum = 0
  Odd_sum = 0
  for i in n:
    #cast i into integer
    i = int(i)
    if i % 2 == 0:
      Even_sum += i 
    else:
      Odd_sum += i
  if Even_sum > Odd_sum :
     return (Even_sum - Odd_sum) 
  else :
     return (Odd_sum - Even_sum)
    
digit = str(input('Enter a number : '))
    
print(digit_sum(digit))
```

Comment: Same remark as abhishek , please refer to stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask